# Get pip install command for all packages installed inside virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a Django application deployed in a virtualenv. I want to move this app to another server now, and for that I need to install all required python packages to the new environment.

Is there a tool to create a pip install command to install all the installed packages within a virtualenv?

For example, if I only installed Django and Gunicorn within a virtualenv, running the desired tool would output the follwing:

pip install django==1.6.6. gunicorn==19.1.0 (including the versions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create requirements:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Install them:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Activate virtual environment

```
$ source .venv/bin/activate
```

Then run `pip freeze`

```
(.venv)my@ubuntu:~/$ pip freeze
astroid==1.3.4
Babel==1.3
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
coverage==3.7.1
d2to1==0.2.11
elasticsearch==1.4.0
flake8==2.3.0
netaddr==0.7.13
netifaces==0.10.4
nose==1.3.4
oslo.config==1.6.0
oslo.i18n==1.3.1
oslo.serialization==1.2.0
oslo.utils==1.2.1
pbr==0.10.0
pecan==0.6.1
pep8==1.6.2
pika==0.9.14
prettytable==0.7.2
pyflakes==0.8.1
Pykka==1.2.0
pylint==1.4.1
python-keystoneclient==0.11.2
pytz==2014.10
requests==2.5.0
setuptools-git==1.1
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.9.0
stevedore==1.1.0
urllib3==1.10.2
waitress==0.8.9
WebOb==1.4
WebTest==2.0.9
WSME==0.5b6
```

This will give you all installed package in that `venv`.

Answer (score 1):

First active virtual env

```
. env/bin/active
```

get list of packages installed in virtualenv

```
pip freeze > list.txt
```

in another environment if you want to install the packages

```
pip install -r list.txt
```

So you could wirte a little script to do these things

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import os
filename = "requirements.txt"

def getlist():
    os.system("pip freeze > %s" %(filename))

def install():
    os.system("pip install -r %s" %(filename))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        print 'Please choose,list or install'
        exit(0)
    if sys.argv[1] == "list":
        getlist()
    elif sys.argv[1] == "install":
        install()
    else:
        print 'Please input list or install'
```